# a comma after the closing in letters

Tags: writing, commas, greetings

When finishing the formal or informal letter is it necessary to use a comma after the closing? For example:

*Yours sincerely,*

*X. Y.*

I have found both alternatives and I would like to know if there is a rule regarding this matter.

Comment: Where have you found both alternatives? That makes a big difference.

Comment: In one of my textbbok there is an example of a formal letter. And the comma is missing there. It surprised me. May be it's a TYPO because I think the comma probably prevails.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't think that "your sincerely" is **not** a **greeting**?  I would probably call it a part of a signature.  A greeting is what we write in the beginning of a letter, no?

Comment: That is not a greeting; it is called a **closing**. See [this image](http://www.cyberbee.com/science/letpart.html), among many others. Also @VictorBazarov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87116/146285) from the ELU question [Sincerely [comma?] name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87114/sincerely-comma-name):

> If you look at a *How to Write A Business Letter* manual, the comma will more than likely be there. For business letters it may matter. For personal letters, there are no strict rules.